# BeautifulSoup find_all not finding all containers of a class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a script to scrape some data off a Zillow page (https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_rent/38.358484,-77.27869,38.218627,-77.498417_rect/X1-SSc26hnbsm6l2u1000000000_8e08t_sse/). Obviously I'm just trying to gather data from every listing. However I cannot grab the data from every listing as it only finds 9 instances of the class I'm searching for ('list-card-addr') even though I've checked the html from listings it does not find and the class exists. Anyone have any ideas for why this is? Here's my simple code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

req_headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
}

url="https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_rent/38.358484,-77.27869,38.218627,-77.498417_rect/X1-SSc26hnbsm6l2u1000000000_8e08t_sse/"

response = requests.get(url, headers=req_headers)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')        
address = soup.find_all(class_='list-card-addr')
print(len(address))
```

[image: Class_instance_not_found]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is stored within a comment. You can regex it out easily as string defining JavaScript object you can handle with json

```
import requests, re, json

r = requests.get('https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_rent/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22savedSearchEnrollmentId%22%3A%22X1-SSc26hnbsm6l2u1000000000_8e08t%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-77.65840518457031%2C%22east%22%3A-77.11870181542969%2C%22south%22%3A38.13250414385234%2C%22north%22%3A38.444339281260426%7D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Afalse%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22mostrecentchange%22%7D%2C%22fsba%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fsbo%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22nc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fore%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22cmsn%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22auc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fr%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A11%7D',
                  headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})

data = json.loads(re.search(r'!--(\{"queryState".*?)-->', r.text).group(1))
print(data['cat1'])
print(data['cat1']['searchList'].keys())
```

Within this are details on pagination and the next url, if applicable, to get all results. You have only asked for page 1 here.

---

[image]

---

For example, print addresses

```
for i in data['cat1']['searchResults']['listResults']:
    print(i['address'])
```

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response. Thanks for your help! One question, how did you know to do that specific search within the text, i.e. re.search(r'!--(\{"queryState".*?)-->', r.text) ? Is that just from printing out the overall result and parsing through the data with your eyes or is there a better strategy? Sorry I'm new at this!

Comment: I did Ctrl + U on the webpage so as to view source - which is what you get in the response with `requests`. I then did Ctrl+F to search for one of the addresses from the webpage and saw that all the data was within a [comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Comment). I could have imported `Comment` from bs4 but chose to use regex to target the specific comment. For the regex, I copied the page source into a regex tool and tested patterns until I had it narrowed to just the JavaScript object of interest.